How can i parametrize rationally an hyperbola with the form $-aX^2 + bY^2 =1$?
I know that a rational parametrization of an hyperbola with the form $$-(\frac{x}{c})^2 + (\frac{y}{d})^2 =1$$ is:
$$(c·\frac{t^2-1}{2t}, d·\frac{1+t^2}{2t})  $$
The problem is that if I transform my hyperbola  $-aX^2 + bY^2 =1$ into $$-(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1/a}})^2 + (\frac{y}{\sqrt{1/b}})^2 =1$$ when I parametrize it I would get $$(\sqrt{1/a}·\frac{t^2-1}{2t}, \sqrt{1/b}·\frac{1+t^2}{2t})  $$ which has non-rational coefficients.
I want to avoid that in order to get a rational paramterization. What can I do? (Maybe try another parametrization?) Is there any way to do it or it's just impossible?

What if $c$ was $7^\frac{1}{4}$. Then your first formula too will not suffice to make the parameters rational. Parameterizing using $x=c\tan\theta,y=d\sec\theta$ seems to be best option

But tan and sec is defined in R, not in Q :(

In the phrase rational parametrization, "rational" is generally understood to mean "a rational function of one variable," not "[some kind of] function with rational coefficients." Is "rational coefficients" a self-imposed constraint...?

If $a$ and $b$ are rational, and if you can find any particular rational point $(x_0, y_0)$ on the hyperbola, then you should be able to use the usual method of finding the other intersection of the hyperbola and the line with rational slope $m$ through $(x_0,y_0)$.  On the other hand, it might certainly be possible that for certain values of $a,b$ there are no rational solutions.

As @Andrew D. Hwang points out in the comments, a rational parameterization of a plane curve $C$ over a field $\Bbb F$ usually means something like a rational map $\Bbb F \setminus \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \to \Bbb F^2$ (or better yet, $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb F) \to \Bbb P^2(\Bbb F)$ with image a relatively open subset of $C$), without further constraints on the coefficients of the function.
In that sense, the parameterization in the question statement with irrational coefficients is still a perfectly good rational parametrization of the hyperbola.
On the other hand, we can consider the hyperbola $C$ as a curve over $\Bbb Q$ (i.e., take $\Bbb F = \Bbb Q$ in the above definition). If $C$ has at least one rational point, say, $P := (X_0, Y_0) \in \Bbb Q^2$, almost any line $\ell$ passing through $\Bbb Q$ will intersect $C$ in another point. We can parameterize an open, dense subset of those lines with their slope, $m$, via $$m \mapsto \ell_m := y - Y_0 = m (x - X_0),$$
and some algebra gives that the intersection of $\ell_m$ with $C$ is at
$$(X(m), Y(m)) := \left(\frac{b X_0 m^2 - 2 b Y_0 m + a X_0}{b m^2 - a}, \frac{-b Y_0 m^2 + 2 a X_0 m - a Y_0}{b m^2 - a}\right),$$
furnishing a rational parametrization of $C$. This parameterization will have image $C \setminus \{(X_0, -Y_0)\}$.
Alternatively, identifying $[A : B] \in \Bbb P^1(\Bbb Q)^*$, with the line $A (X - X_0) + B(Y - Y_0) = 0$ through $P$, an analogous projective computation gives an embedding $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb Q)^* \to \Bbb P^2(\Bbb Q)$,
$$[A, B] \mapsto \left[b X_0 A^2 + 2 b Y_0 A B + a X_0 B^2, -b Y_0 A^2 - 2 a X_0 A B - a Y_0 B^2, b A^2 - a B^2\right] .$$
N.b. for some $a, b$ there are no rational points on $C$ at all, e.g., when $a = b = \frac12$ (to see as much, suppose $(X_0, Y_0)$ a rational point on that curve, clear denominators, and reduce modulo $4$).

I would argue that this is not possible.
You can get a rational parametrization of any conic defined by the parameter values for three points on the conic. This is a projective concept, based on the cross ratio (explained in more detail below), and as such it considers infinity a regular parameter value, and points at infinity part of the projective plane. Conventionally one picks points for the parameter values $0,1,\infty$, but any other three values would work just as well.
If those three defining points have coordinates that are rational in the parameters defining the conic (i.e. $a$ and $b$ in your case) then the rational parametrization could keep that property. So if you can name three points on the hyperbola with coordinates that are rational in $a,b$, then I can give you a parametrization of the whole hyperbola. But I can't see such three points.
For further detail: If you have $A,B,C$ as three points on the conic, then the cross ratio $(A,B;C,P)_Q$ denotes the cross ratio of the four lines $AQ$, $BQ$, $CQ$, $PQ$ where $Q$ shall be any other point on the conic. The value doesn't depend on $Q$ at all, but it will characterize the point $P$. This is a function from point on conic to parameter value. The converse is possible as well, where you start with three lines, use the parameter value to construct a fourth, then intersect that with a conic.
